# Commutative squares in Beamer

Tags: beamer, diagrams, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I'm trying to draw a commutative square in a beamer presentation, but my attempts haven't been successful.

For example, if I use this method (from [here](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/rtg/ProfessionalDevelopment/beamer-tikz.pdf)):

```
\begin{tikzcd}
A \dar{g} \rar{f} & B \dar{h} \\
C \rar{i} & D
\end{tikzcd}
```

it won't compile (I get something like "Package pgf Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode."). How do I fix it?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\begin{document}
\title{Test Title}   
\author{Author} 
\date{\today} 

\frame{\titlepage} 

\frame{\frametitle{Table of contents}\tableofcontents} 


\section{Test Section} 

\frame{\frametitle{Test Frame} 
\pause

\begin{tikzcd}
A \dar{g} \rar{f} & B \dar{h} \\
C \rar{i} & D
\end{tikzcd}

}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use either an `ampersand replacement` or add `fragile` to the options of the frame. For instance, `\frame{\frametitle{Test Frame} 
\pause

\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
A \dar{g} \rar{f} \& B \dar{h} \\
C \rar{i} \& D
\end{tikzcd}

}` compiles. (If you load `tikz-cd`, you do not need `\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}` separately.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is is answered in the comments.